# Bigram for Hexadecimal Values

Tags: python, nlp, hex

I was trying to find out the bigrams for hexadecimal values. I tried using nltk.ngrams method but I am not getting the desired result.
I have a pure python I wrote myself but I am getting over 64K unique combinations which is very high and it wont fit into my machine learning problem.
Below is my code:

```
lst='0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0a,0b,0c,0d,0e,0f,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,1a,1b,1c,1d,1e,1f,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,2a,2b,2c,2d,2e,2f,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,3a,3b,3c,3d,3e,3f,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,4a,4b,4c,4d,4e,4f,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,5a,5b,5c,5d,5e,5f,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,6a,6b,6c,6d,6e,6f,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,7a,7b,7c,7d,7e,7f,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,8a,8b,8c,8d,8e,8f,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,9a,9b,9c,9d,9e,9f,a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,aa,ab,ac,ad,ae,af,b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,ba,bb,bc,bd,be,bf,c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,ca,cb,cc,cd,ce,cf,d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,da,db,dc,dd,de,df,e0,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9,ea,eb,ec,ed,ee,ef,f0,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,fa,fb,fc,fd,fe,ff'

string=''
for i in lst.split(','):
    string=string+i+' '

str_lst=[]
bigram=[]
for i in lst.split(','):
    str_lst.append(i)
for i in str_lst:
    for j in str_lst:
        if not i+j in str_lst:
            bigram.append(i+j)
```

Can some one help me in getting the bigrams for this hexa values. If bigrams are above thousand it wont help my situation.

Comment: I'm unsure of what you are asking for - do you want every possible combination of 4 hexadecimal characters (i.e. all possible values that can be represented in 2 bytes)?
Because if that's the case, there's no getting around the fact that there will be (2^8) * (2^8) = 2^16 = 65,536 possible "bigrams".

Answer (score 0):

This defines possibilities for 2 char bigrams, but it is equivalent to your manual list. If you want more combinations to be represented you'll need to increase the dimensionality.

```
 bigrams = [hex(x)[2:] for x in range(256)]
```